# Help with NPV question

Tags: loans, homework

Consider two options to buy equipment for your emergency department.  You are given the choice to pay $15,000 in cash now, or pay zero upfront, but make four payments of $5,000.  If the cost of capital is 2.5%, which is the best based on NPV?

Comment: What frequency are the payments to be made?  Annually?  Quarterly?  Daily?

Comment: My professor didn't provide me with that information but let's say it's annually.

Comment: What answer did *you* get when you* plugged these numbers into the NPV formula?  Please show your work!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This might help illustrate the solution. I look at NPV of each cash flow. i.e. take each payment and calculate the PV of that future amount. $5000/1.025 means that $5000 in a year is worth $4878 if discounted by the 2.5%. The effect compounds, (1.025)^2 for year 2 etc.

At a glance, a total $20K would require a far higher cost of capital to make those payments preferable to the $15K lump sum.

Comment: Looks like the interest rate would need to be 12.59% or so in order for the two to be comparable.